# How do i get my class to use an array from outside the class?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm currently trying to get back into object oriented programming How do i get my array inside my class? Global doesn't seam to cut it.

```
<?
$systems = file_get_contents('https://api.eveonline.com/map/Sovereignty.xml.aspx');
$systems = explode("<row ",$systems);
//print_r($systems);
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($systems); $i++) {

    //system name
    $systemnames=explode("solarSystemName=",$systems[$i]);
    $systemnames=explode('"',$systemnames[1]);
    $systemnames=$systemnames[1];

    //system id
    $systemid=explode("solarSystemID=",$systems[$i]);
    $systemid=explode('"',$systemid[1]);
    $systemid=$systemid[1];

    $systembyid[$systemid]=$systemnames;
    $systembyname[$systemnames]=$systemid;
}   

class Systems{    

    public function __construct()
    {
        global $systembyid;
        global $systembyname;
    }

    function getSystems($system)
    {
        if (is_numeric($system) && $systembyid[$system]) {
            return $systembyid[$system];
        }
        elseif($systembyname[$system]){
            return $systembyname[$system];
        }
        else{
           return "Error: Invalid system id or name";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the values into the constructor like this, also if you use the `&` you are just passing a reference and not making a copy of the whole array.

```
class Systems{    

    private $sysyembyid;
    private $systembyname;

    public function __construct(&$systembyid, &$systembyname)
    {
        $this->systembyid = $systembyid;
        $this->systembyname = $systembyname;
    }

    function getSystems($system){
        if(is_numeric($system) && $this->systembyid[$system]){
        return $this->systembyid[$system];
    }
    elseif($this->systembyname[$system]){
            return $this->systembyname[$system];
        }
        else{
           return "Error: Invalid system id or name";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use ***Dependency Injection***. Dependency Injection is when you inject your object's dependencies via the constructor. This ensures that the object will have its dependencies at creation.

```
class Systems {
    protected $systembyid;
    protected $systembyname;

    public function __construct($systembyid, $systembyname)
    {
        $this->systembyid = $systembyid;
        $this->systembyname = $systembyname;
    }

    public function getSystems($system) {
        //Access them with $this-> like below
        $this->systembyid[$system];
        $this->systembyname[$system];
    }
}
```

***Note*** *If you want to be able to modify `$systembyid` and `$systembyname` outside of the class, and see the changes within the class, you can pass references to `__construct()` instead, by specifying the parameters as references:*

```
public function __construct(&$systembyid, &$systembyname)
{
    $this->systembyid = $systembyid;
    $this->systembyname = $systembyname;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can pass them as parameters to your `getSystems()` method.

```
class Systems() {
    public function getSystems($system, $systembyid, $systembyname) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

The main drawbacks with this approach is that you always have to pass them as parameters to the method, and the method signature could get quite long.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use the `global` key word with var in the function where you use it, in this case `getSystems()` (bad) or pass them into the constructor or the function where you use them, or set them:

Probably the most common case:

```
public function __construct($s1, $s2)
    {
        $this->systembyid = $s1
        $this->systembyname = $s2
    }
//then use $this->systembyid etc in other functions
```

Or better yet, why not put all that processing code in a function off the class like `processSystems()` and set the vars there:

```
public function processSystems($file) {
    $systems = file_get_contents($file);
    $systems = explode("<row ",$systems);
    //print_r($systems);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= count($systems); $i++) {

        //system name
        $systemnames=explode("solarSystemName=",$systems[$i]);
        $systemnames=explode('"',$systemnames[1]);
        $systemnames=$systemnames[1];

        //system id
        $systemid=explode("solarSystemID=",$systems[$i]);
        $systemid=explode('"',$systemid[1]);
        $systemid=$systemid[1];

        $systembyid[$systemid]=$systemnames;
        $systembyname[$systemnames]=$systemid;
    }   
    $this->systembyid = $systemnames;
    $this->systembyname = $systemid;
}
```

Aside from that, I would say look into `simple_xml` or `DOM` for the XML parsing.

Also, you are storing the exact same data in each array.  Just use one and either lookup the key or the value.